# Mongoose save : saving failed without error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm building a simple app with mongoose to save some data from an IRC channel.
I have a remote database on a OVH VPS where I can access and log-in without any problems.

However when I try to save some data on it I can't go it with my javascript code.

Here is the data I would like to save :

```
"use strict"
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

var UserPointDataSchema = new Schema({
                                        username: String,
                                        value: Number,
                                        channel: String,
                                        timestamp: Number
                                        });
var UserPointDataModel =  mongoose.model('UserPointData',UserPointDataSchema);


class UserPointData{
    constructor(username,value,channel){
        this.username =  username;
        this.value =  value;
        this.channel =  channel;
        this.timestamp =Date.now();

        this.mongooseModel = this.toMoogoseModel();

        return this;
    }

    toMoogoseModel(){
        return UserPointDataModel.hydrate(this);
    }

    save(){
        this.mongooseModel.save(function (err, product, numAffected) {
            if (err){
                console.log(err);
            }
            console.log(err);
            console.log(product);
            console.log(numAffected);
        });
    }
}

module.exports = UserPointData;
```

Here is the output on the console :

> null 
>   { username: 'breci',   value: 1,   channel: 'breci',   timestamp:
>   1478897691976 }
>   0

- MongoDB version : 3.2.10
- Mongoose version : 4.6.6

I checked the logs, no identification problem, no error too.

Someone has an idea why it is not working ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by changing the toMongooseModel() method

Here is the new one if someone has the same problem need it :

```
    toMoogoseModel(){
    var data = {
        username :this.username ,
        value: this.value,
        channel: this.channel,
        timestamp: this.timestamp
    }

    var res = new UserPointDataModel(data);

    return res;
}
```

If anyone know why the hydrate method didn't work I'm curious to know.